# Banshee: codec for playing this media type not available

Tags: banshee, mp3, codecs, gstreamer

For some reason Banshee does not play all of my mp3. I installed pretty much every suggested codec, but still nothing. Every time I try to play mp3 I get this:

[image]

If I press install usually it says "dependencies cannot be resolved", but now I wanted to make screenshot of that but nothing appears after pressing `install`.

P.s. I did `sudo apt-get install gstreamer0.10-plugins` among many other things.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, turns out banshee comes with optional dependencies which don't get installed automatically but you can search and install them.

I'm using archlinux so i did `pacman -Qi banshee` *this command queries for information about the package* kinda like `dpkg-query -s banshee` *(sorry for archlinux references though)* then I saw two optional 
dependencies.

**Output**

```
Name            : banshee
Version         : 2.6.2-9
Description     : Music management and playback for GNOME
Architecture    : x86_64
URL             : http://banshee.fm/
Licenses        : MIT
Groups          : None
Provides        : None
Depends On      : libxxf86vm  gst-plugins-base-libs  mono-addins  dbus-sharp-glib  webkitgtk2
                  libsoup-gnome  gdata-sharp  taglib-sharp  gudev-sharp  gkeyfile-sharp  gconf-sharp
                  libmtp  libgpod  mono-zeroconf  hicolor-icon-theme  media-player-info  gst-plugins-bad
                  mono-upnp  gst-plugins-good  gvfs
Optional Deps   : gst-plugins-ugly: Extra media codecs [installed]
                  gst-libav: Extra media codecs [installed]
                  brasero: CD burning [installed]
Required By     : None
Optional For    : None
Conflicts With  : None
Replaces        : None
Installed Size  : 14.17 MiB
Packager        : Antonio Rojas <arojas@archlinux.org>
Build Date      : Sun 07 Aug 2016 09:50:47 PM EAT
Install Date    : Fri 30 Sep 2016 06:00:29 PM EAT
Install Reason  : Explicitly installed
Install Script  : No
Validated By    : Signature
```

**Notice** the Optional Deps field, with

```
Optional Deps   : gst-plugins-ugly: Extra media codecs [installed]
                  gst-libav: Extra media codecs [installed]
                  brasero: CD burning [installed]
```

They are now listed as [installed] but weren't.

So I installed everything listed in `Optional Deps` field then closed banshee (with all it's child process
that don't close when I click the close button) *you can aswell reboot*.

Start banshee and everything works!